# No se guardan los datos de power app en la misma fila de dataverse usando patch

Tags: powerapps

Estoy haciendo una power app móvil usando dataverse.

Tengo varias pantallas y columnas en mi tabla, quiero que los datos de cada pantalla se guarden según la columna que les corresponda dentro de la misma fila, estoy usando

patch(nombre de mi tabla) ,
Defaults (nombre de mi tabla);

si guarda datos pero no en la misma fila cada vez que guarda lo guarda en la columna pero salta fila como puedo solucionar esto?